# How do I get a list value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm able to get the list ID but not the value...what am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
$('#listParams ').append('<li id="1">Item 1</li>');
$('#listParams ').append('<li id="2">Item 2</li>');


var items = "";
var lis = $("#listParams li");
for(var no=0;no<lis.length;no++){
    if(items.length > 0) {
        items = items + "|";
    }
    //items = items + lis[no].id + '-|-' + lis[no].text; 
    items = items + lis[no].id + '-|-' + lis[no].val;               
}

alert(items);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the value and the id for each list value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var items = [];
$("#listParams li").each(function() {
      items.push(this.id + "-|-" + $(this).text());
});
alert(items.join());
```

Comment: I don't `<li>` tags are supposed to have value attributes.  Edit: It's [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2).

Comment: @Rocket your quite right, fixed. Brain freeze & was thinking of <option>s

Answer (score 0):

Its an `<li>` element so you need to get the innerHTML , not the value.

```js
 alert($("li#1").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

One easier approach is to use `map()`:

```
var itemsAndValues =    $('#listParams li').map(
                                function(){
                                    return this.id + ':' + $(this).text();
                                }).get().join(',');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDfCS/1/).